# Differences between Hadoop versions

Tags: hadoop

I'm a Hadoop beginner. Currently my biggest problem is trying to navigate between configurations and codes found online that are made for different Hadoop versions. It's sometimes very hard to know which examples are suitable for my version as the examples rarely mention version numbers.

My biggest problems are:

1. Which configuration options in the configuration files are meant for which version - which are replaced, new or deprecated
2. Which classes in the API are replaced by which other classes (approximately)

I understand a thorough explanation can't be given here, but I haven't been able to find comprehensive guides online either. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The major configuration differences are in Hadoop 1 and Hadoop 2. You should use latest stable version of Hadoop 2, details are [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/).

You can find some helpful configuration [here](http://www.alexjf.net/blog/distributed-systems/hadoop-yarn-installation-definitive-guide)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a guide for the transition. Something that says "Settings A is now setting B in new version" etc. And the same for the API